# Using MutableLiveData, update data from Activity to Fragment

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I have used **SharedViewModel** concept to pass data from Activity to Fragment

Like in Activity there is **EditText**, based on whatever I write in EditText, **RecyclerView** of Fragment should show filtered data.

**ViewModel:**

```
fun onSearchChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
    mutableChangedText.postValue(s.toString())
}

fun getSearchChangedText(): MutableLiveData<String> {
    return mutableChangedText
}
```

**Fragment:** I am observing data in Fragment using below method, but here it's not observing

```
private lateinit var sharedVM: SharedViewModel

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    fragmentBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_list_passwords, container, false)
    sharedVM = ViewModelProvider(this).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
    fragmentBinding.appListViewModel = sharedVM
    observeSearchText()
    return fragmentListPasswordBinding.root
}
private fun observeSearchText() {
    sharedVM.getSearchChangedText().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        Log.d(TAG, "value = $it")
    })
}
```

**MainActivity:** If I use same code in Activity class where EditText is, it is working fine.
    private lateinit var sharedVM: SharedViewModel

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    activityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
    sharedVM = ViewModelProvider(this).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
    activityMainBinding.appListViewModel = sharedVM

    observeSearchText()
}

private fun observeSearchText() {
    sharedVM.getSearchChangedText().observe(this, Observer {
        Log.d(TAG,"value = $it") 
    })
}
```

As per @Hein Htet Aung's answer if I change this to activity, I am getting below compile-time error

[image]

**Answer:**

Thanks to Hein Htet Aung

I got solution using below code in Fragment

```
sharedVM = ViewModelProvider(activity as MainActivity).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
```

Comment: From above code, i dont see problem. Check Logcat maybe for warning, error..

Comment: No error is showing :( only MainActivity's Log is showing

Comment: How do u inject the sharedViewmodel in fragment?

Comment: Yeah, maybe injecting is problem..

Comment: Let me update code

Comment: sharedVM = ViewModelProvider(activity).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
convert to activity

Comment: Sorry I could not understand

Comment: hee, sry. see the answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside fragment, convert this line

```
sharedVM = ViewModelProvider(this).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
```

to

```
sharedVM = ViewModelProvider(activity).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
```

By using `activity`, viewmodelprovider will provide same viewmodel from activity

Comment: It shows me an error, Type mismatch Required: ViewModelStoreOwner Found FragmentActivity

Comment: let me check. I m using like that and working fine.

Comment: are u using androidx?

Comment: Yes, I am using AndroidX

Comment: sry, just to make sure. which version of appcompat u using now?

Comment: oh try with `?.let`

Comment: I have done using ViewModelProvider(activity as MainActivity), now it's working, thanks

Comment: can try like this? 
     activity?.let {
            ViewModelProvider(it, viewModelFactory)
                .get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
        }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210637/discussion-between-siddhpura-amit-and-hein-htet-aung).